# Using GetDiskFreeSpaceEx on CIFS share (C#)

Tags: c#, winapi, cifs

I'm trying to use WIN Api function `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` to get available disk space on CIFS share. I discovered that this function return different values after the disk have been formatted.

So here are my steps:

1. Create the CIFS shared folder.
2. Call `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`. It returns correct value.
3. Format the disk with shared folder.
4. Recreate folder on the disk. (Sharing wasn't be stopped)
5. Call `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`. It returns 0.
6. Call `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` again. Now it returns correct value. And all next calling of this function returns right value.

I also discovered that when I stop sharing the folder after formatting the disk and than begin to share it again, the `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` always return correct value.

Do you have any ideas about such situation?

Comment: A disk does not have any free space until it is formatted. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: This is probably a network redirectory bug.  But surely one that you *never* care about in practice, formatting a disk while its being shared is a very strange thing to do.

Comment: I agree with other comments that this is a non-problem in practice but, out of interest, what operating system is running on the server with the share?  I suspect that GetDiskFreeSpaceEx is faithfully reporting whatever the remote server tells it, and the problem lies there.